# Batch scanning how much space is on a hard drive

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I am making a program the speeds up your pc and one of the things it does is delete temp files does any one know how I could check how much space is on the hard-drive preferable in KB. My OS is windows 7 ultimate 32-bit

Comment: Try [diskpart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx) with the `/s` argument and a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try this, explanation is in the code:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-c %cd:~0,3%') do set "Bytes=%%~a"
echo(Free space in %cd:~0,2%
echo(Bytes: %Bytes%
set /a KiloByte=%Bytes:~0,-3%
echo(KByte: %KiloByte%
set /a MegaByte=%Bytes:~0,-6%
echo(MByte: %MegaByte%
set /a GigaByte=MegaByte/1024
echo(GByte: %GigaByte%
set /a TeraByte=GigaByte/1024
echo(TByte: %TeraByte%
```

Please note, `cmd` cannot calculate with numbers greater 2,147,483,647 `(2^31)-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to play a bit with eliminating first row if no header is needed.
wmic is used to get free space for each disk. You may need to add filter "where DriveType=3" if

```
    @echo off
    SetLocal enabledelayedexpansion 
    set command="wmic /node:"%COMPUTERNAME%" LogicalDisk Where Get DeviceID,FreeSpace"
    for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in ('%command%') do (
        set disk=%%a
        set freeSpace=%%b
        if "%%a" NEQ ""  if "%%b" NEQ "" (
            set disk=%%a
            set freeSpace=%%b
            echo !disk! !freeSpace!
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a batch file using powershell from a modified previous post, and which returns free space KB in power of 2 figures. Change 1024 to 1000 for decimal KB.

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" (
echo %%1 is a drive letter such as c
echo and returns free disk space from that drive in KB 
pause
goto :eof
)
>  s.ps1 echo Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE Caption='%1:'" `
>> s.ps1 echo  ^| %% { 
>> s.ps1 echo      $f = [System.Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1024,0);
>> s.ps1 echo      $t = [System.Math]::Round($_.Size/1024,0);
>> s.ps1 echo      Write-Host ('Freespace ' + $f);
>> s.ps1 echo  }

powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command ".\s.ps1"
del s.ps1
pause
goto :eof
```